# Thinkfan refuses to start

Tags: command-line

Thinkfan used to work before, but when I try to start it now, I get the following error messages. Does anyone have experience with that issue? I can't make any sense of it.

```
[~] $ sudo /etc/init.d/thinkfan start
[sudo] password for daniel: 
[....] Starting thinkfan (via systemctl): thinkfan.serviceJob for thinkfan.service failed. See 'systemctl status thinkfan.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
failed!
[~] $ sudo systemctl status thinkfan.service 
● thinkfan.service - simple and lightweight fan control program
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/thinkfan.service; disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2014-10-16 23:47:10 BST; 10s ago
Process: 3449 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/thinkfan (code=exited, status=4)

Oct 16 23:47:10 daniel-debian thinkfan[3449]: thinkfan 0.9.1 starting...
Oct 16 23:47:10 daniel-debian thinkfan[3449]: /etc/thinkfan.conf:33:sensor /sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input
Oct 16 23:47:10 daniel-debian thinkfan[3449]: WARNING: The `sensor' keyword is deprecated. Please use the `hwmon' or `tp_thermal' keywords instead!
Oct 16 23:47:10 daniel-debian systemd[1]: thinkfan.service: control process exited, code=exited status=4
Oct 16 23:47:10 daniel-debian systemd[1]: Failed to start simple and lightweight fan control program.
Oct 16 23:47:10 daniel-debian systemd[1]: Unit thinkfan.service entered failed state.
[~] $ sudo journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Thu 2014-10-16 23:46:31 BST, end at Thu 2014-10-16 23:47:33 BST. --
Oct 16 23:47:33 daniel-debian sudo[3492]: daniel : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/daniel ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xn
Oct 16 23:47:33 daniel-debian sudo[3492]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo nano /etc/thinkfan.conf
```

Go to configuration file, there scroll down and change

```
sensor /sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input
```

to

```
hwmon /sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input
```

or

```
tp_thermal /sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input
```

This is what that error explanation is saying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't verify whether this works, but this seems like it could work, so I've accepted it.

Comment: fwiw it's `hwmon` not `hwon`...